# SQL - Count distinct once a condition from the same column is met

Tags: sql, distinct

I can find plenty of examples for this online, but the specific part of it being in the same column is what seems to be throwing off any solution I can implement.

I have a column with `ID` another with `date`, and a 3rd with a `city`.

I am trying to find all instances where for each ID there are 2 different values for the city within a certain time frame.

I can get all of this info using `case when` in SQL, however, there is one more condition that I need to meet which is where I'm having the issues.

The city column has a lot of blanks ('') in it, and these are the ones I'm interested in. So where I say 2 different cities above, one of those 2 has to be blank.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might go about this?

---

Adding info requested from comments:

---

A sample table of the data I'm looking at would be:

[image]

Here I'm trying to determine what cities I can fill in directly from the ID.

So in this case, for each ID, if there is only 1 corresponding city we can fill in that city, so row 3 shows an ID of 8 with a blank city, so we know that there are only 2 entries for ID 8, one is Dallas and the other is blank, therefore we're going to populate the blank one with "Dallas"

However, if we look at ID 2 for example, here we have 3 distinct Cities, "London", "Manchester" and ""
In this case we can't populate the blank as we don't have enough info.

However, if we look at ID 6, this has 2 distinct cities, however neither of them are blank. This means that we again, don't have enough information.

So what I need to determine is IDs that have 2 distinct entries for cities, but 1 of those entries needs to be ""

I am also using the date to ensure that the delta between both occurrences is less than a particular number of days (I'm working off 90 for the moment)

What I have done so far is:

```
select GID, datediff(day,min(DT),max(DT)) as Days_Delta, count(distinct City) as Unique_City,
  case 
    when (count(distinct City) = 2 and datediff(day,min(DT),max(DT)) < 90) then 'Transform'
    else ''
  end As transform_case
from My_Table
group by GID
```

Comment: please post a sample table and add the dbms you're working with

Comment: And the SQL you’ve managed to write so far

Comment: Why do you store blanks? NULL has a purpose, don't be afraid of it.

Answer (score 0):

See an example. Comments in query text

```
with t1 as ( 
select * 
  ,datediff(d,lag(dt,1,dt)over(partition by gid order by dt,city),dt) ddif
from test
  )
,t2 as( -- Divide rows to groups, where datediff between seq.rows is<90.
  select *
      ,sum(case when ddif is null or ddif<=90 then 0 else 1 end)
         over(partition by gid order by dt,city) grn
  from t1
)
,t3 as(
  select *
      ,dense_rank()over(partition by gid,grn order by city) rn
       -- check for 1 or more blank (empty) city  for every group
      ,sum(case when city='' then 1 else 0 end)
             over(partition by gid,grn order by city) isEmpty
      ,max(city)over(partition by gid,grn) city1
  from t2
)
,t4 as( -- max rank in group - numbers of different cities in group, including empty
  select *
      ,max(rn)over(partition by gid,grn ) maxrn
  from t3
)
select * 
  ,case when city='' and maxrn=2 then city1
   end newcity
from t4
order by gid,grn,dt,city
```

| gid | dt | city | ddif | grn | rn | isEmpty | city1 | maxrn | newcity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-16 | Berlin | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | Berlin | 1 | null |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | Berlin | 107 | 1 | 2 | 1 | Berlin | 2 | null |
| 1 | 2023-01-13 |  | 12 | 1 | 1 | 1 | Berlin | 2 | Berlin |
| 2 | 2022-10-10 | Manchester | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | Manchester | 1 | null |
| 2 | 2023-01-21 | London | 103 | 1 | 2 | 1 | London | 2 | null |
| 2 | 2023-03-20 |  | 58 | 1 | 1 | 1 | London | 2 | London |
| 2 | 2023-03-20 | London | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | London | 2 | null |
| 3 | 2022-09-16 | Paris | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | Paris | 1 | null |
| 3 | 2023-01-13 | Paris | 119 | 1 | 1 | 0 | Paris | 1 | null |
| 3 | 2023-02-09 | Paris | 27 | 1 | 1 | 0 | Paris | 1 | null |
| 4 | 2022-11-17 | New York | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | New York | 1 | null |
| 4 | 2023-01-09 | New York | 53 | 0 | 1 | 0 | New York | 1 | null |
| 4 | 2023-03-23 | New York | 73 | 0 | 1 | 0 | New York | 1 | null |
| 5 | 2023-02-21 | Sydney | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | Sydney | 1 | null |
| 5 | 2023-03-20 | Sydney | 27 | 0 | 1 | 0 | Sydney | 1 | null |
| 6 | 2022-09-16 | Edinburgh | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | Glasgow | 2 | null |
| 6 | 2022-10-20 | Glasgow | 34 | 0 | 2 | 0 | Glasgow | 2 | null |
| 7 | 2022-09-16 | Dublin | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | Dublin | 1 | null |
| 7 | 2022-09-16 | Dublin | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | Dublin | 1 | null |
| 7 | 2023-03-23 |  | 188 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  | 1 | null |
| 8 | 2022-10-10 | Dallas | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | Dallas | 1 | null |
| 8 | 2023-02-21 |  | 134 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  | 1 | null |
| 10 | 2022-09-16 | Belfast | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | Belfast | 1 | null |

"there are only 2 entries for ID 8, one is Dallas and the other is blank, therefore we're going to populate the blank one with "Dallas" - there 134 days between 2 rows. I consider them as 2 separate groups, each with 1 row. In this case we can't populate the blank one with "Dallas". This requires further clarification.
Also, for test data row (1,2022-09-16,  Berlin) and rows thru 107 days(1,   2023-01-01,Berlin),(1,2023-01-13,'') we can populate blank with 'Berlin'.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help! It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it gave me the info to adapt to what I required! Very much appreciated!